# How to read streaming datasets from AWS SQS?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-sqs, spark-structured-streaming

For Spark streaming there are [connectors](https://github.com/imapi/spark-sqs-receiver) that can achieve this functionality.

Unfortunately for Spark structured streaming I couldn't find any as it's a newer technology. Is there a way to connect to a source using a Spark streaming connector? Or is there a way to create a custom connector similar to the way one can be created in a [spark streaming](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-custom-receivers.html) application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to connect to a source using a spark streaming connector?

No idea.

> Or is there a way to create a custom connector similar to the way one can be created in a spark streaming application?

With no experience in AWS SQS I however think that if Spark Streaming supports it, Spark Structured Streaming should too.

The streaming [Source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/Source.scala#L28) interface allows you to implement a custom data source to load streaming datasets, possibly from AWS SQS, too.

Use [KafkaSource](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/kafka-0-10-sql/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/kafka010/KafkaSource.scala) or [TextSocketSource](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/socket.scala) as the templates.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, AWS SQS might not fit for streaming requirements compared to using AWS Kinesis Streams, Kinesis Firehorse and Kinesis Analytics which are focused on Streaming data processing, storage and analytics.

You can event connect [Spark Streaming + Kinesis Integration](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kinesis-integration.html) to configure Spark Streaming to receive data from Kinesis.

I don't think there is a spark streaming connector at the moment for AWS SQS but you should be able to write a custom connector using AWS SQS SDK to Poll the Data from Queue and Push to the Spark Stream.

Comment: I wonder why you say "spark streaming connector" if the OP asked about "Unfortunately for spark structured streaming I couldn't find any as it's a newer technology."?

Comment: Hi Jacek I couldn't understand your question quite. Can you elaborate it further?

Comment: The question is about Spark Structured Streaming, but you used Spark Streaming in your answer. The modules are different.